# How can I read 你让我做什么我就做什么?

Tags: grammar, idioms

> 我今天听你的安排,你让我做什么我就做什么。
>
> For today, I will listen(obey) to your arrangement(s). I'll do whatever what you let me do.

The above English translation was made by me.

I've been stuggling to understand the below sentence.

> 你让我做什么我就做什么
>
> you let me do something then I do something.

Directly reading above English sentence seems not make sensing.

I guess that 都 or 也 can be inserted somewhere inside 你让我做什么我就做什么

Or is there some resembling idioms or representations exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

你让我做什么我就做什么 = 你想(让)我做什么我就做什么 - I'll do whatever you want me to do.

Answer (score 2):

你让我做什么, 我就做什么。= If you want me to do it, then I will do it. (什么 indicates a thing specified by that person.)

(1) This is a very useful structure of sentences in the Chinese language. For example,

你要什么，我就给你买什么。= 你要什么东西，我就给你买什么东西。= I will buy whatever you want. = I will buy it if you want it.

你做了什么，我就吃什么。= 你做了什么饭，我就吃什么饭。= I would like to have whatever you cook. = It doesn't matter what you cook, I would like it.

你说什么对，就是什么对。= Whatever you think is correct, that is correct.

你说哪个好，就是哪个好。= Whichever you think is better, that is better.

你想啥时候走，就啥时候走。= Whenever you want to go, we will go.

(2) This structure can be translated into English using the following words,

Whatever, Whichever, Whenever, Wherever, Whoever, However.

Those words just correspond to 5W1H.

(3) Those English words can be in turn translated into 无论，不论，不管。for example, 女人对男人说，结婚以后，不管你去哪里，我都跟你去。

(4) The words 都 and 也 can be used in similar situations. For example,

买衣服时，女人问男人，你说，我是买红色的呢，还是粉色的呢？

男人说，都行。

男人也可以说，红色的也行，粉色的也行。

男人还可以说，你喜欢什么颜色的，就买什么颜色的。